# What does class pointer* mean?

Tags: c++

I got this syntax I don't really understand:

```
class USphereComponent* ProxSphere;
```

I think this means create a class, but is this class a pointer?

But the result is just creating an object called ProxSphere from an existing class USphereComponent.

What does this syntax actually mean, and what is its usage?

Comment: It's a class pointer declaration, no more no less.

Comment: It's a class declaration combined with a pointer declaration. It's not the same without `class`, @bereal.

Comment: Do you know C? While classes in C++ can be used as types, you can also use old C-style declarations with classes and structures just like is done in this case.

Comment: Used as an example in *[The Tyrannical Mods of Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c&t=6m30s)*. (But note that there is a ***lot*** of factual information in that video which is flat out wrong, for example, that Google would take voting on answers into consideration for search ranking).

Comment: Other wrong information: That there is a Catch-22 between closing and editing ([at 07 min 45 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c&t=7m45s)). It is even called the crux of the problem with Stack Overflow. There isn't. Users don't need any reputation points for editing their own questions (only other users' posts).

Comment: @PeterMortensen The person that wanted to answer the question was unable to because the question remained closed even after the original poster edited it. So in this case, it was accurate.

Answer (score 12):

```
class Someotherclass; // That has not been defined yet

class HelloWorld
{
    Someotherclass* my_pointer;
};
```

Or an alternative:

```
class HelloWorld
{
    class Someotherclass* my_pointer;
};
```

The first one is obviously the correct one if you have multiple pointers (or references) to such class that has not been defined yet.

Is the second better? (I don't know) if you only need to do it once, otherwise doing

```
class HelloWorld
{
    class Someotherclass* my_pointer;
    class Someotherclass* my_pointer2;
    class Someotherclass* my_pointer3;

    void func(class Someotherclass* my_pointer, class Someotherclass& my_ref);
};
```

may not be the best.

Comment: Thanks! so I can assume that someotherclass* myPointer is almost the same as class Someotherclass* myPointer?

Comment: It's the exactly the same, both are pointers to class Someotherclass.

Answer (score 8):

[Jts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244342/what-does-class-pointer-mean/35244377#35244377) is correct. I'd like to add a use case for it:

This is mostly used when you have a circular class dependency.

Like:

```cpp
class A { B* binst; };
class B { A* ainst; };
```

That wouldn't compile since B isn't previously known.

Therefore you would first declare class B.

```cpp
class B;
class A { B* binst; };
class B { A* ainst; };
```

Or as mentioned, you can use syntactic sugar:

```cpp
class A { class B* binst; };
class B { A* ainst; };
```

Such a dependency might be a code smell. It also might be ok or even necessary. If you have it, you should carefully think if you can't do it in some other yet convenient way.

Answer (score 4):

That particular syntax is called a "[forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)". It is used to declare a type that has not been defined yet.

This is basically telling the compiler "There exists a class type named `USphereComponent` that you haven't seen yet that will come up later in the code. Please don't yell at me if you see pointers of that type". This allows you to declare *pointer and reference* for that forward-declared type.

Writing:

```
class USphereComponent* ProxSphere;
```

Is really just the equivalent of writing this:

```
class USphereComponent;
USphereComponent* ProxSphere;
```

The only difference with the second syntax, is that you only need to forward-declare the type once when you do it like this `class USphereComponent;`, otherwise you need to use the first syntax and add the `class` keyword before each usage of `USphereComponent`.

There are two main reasons why you may want to use a forward declaration:

1. This is probably the most common usage of forward-declaration in [Unreal Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine#Unreal_Engine_3). In header (.h) files, forward-declaration allows you to use pointer of classes for which you did not `#include` the corresponding header file. In our particular example that means that forward-declaring USphereComponent means that we don't need a `#include "SphereComponent.h"` statement (if we're just trying to pass a USphereComponent around that is).

   Typically when that happens, the #include statement is simply done in the .cpp file. There are mainly two advantages of reducing the number of includes in your header files:

   - Compilation times are faster. Mind you, this mostly has significant impact on a codebase as big as Unreal's.
   - This reduces the number of public dependencies of you module (by making them "private" since your includes are now in your .cpp). This makes your module easier to be depended upon and also makes its interface cleaner.
2. Like other answers have said, forward-declaration can be used to break circular dependencies when you have two types that depends on each other in the same file:

   ```
   class B;
   class A
   {
       B* foo;
   };
   class B
   {
       A* bar;
   };
   ```